# How to invoke a Django function without redirecting to a new page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-views

I am working on bookmarking of articles. I want to add the article in bookmarks when a button `Add To Bookmark`is clicked.

Using Django, the conventional way of doing it would be redirecting to the bookmarks page by passing the slug of the article, and handling the information in the `views.py`.

Currently, under bookmarks page function in `views.py`, I have set of code which saves the article to bookmark object of the current user,

```
user_instance        = get_object_or_404(User,username = request.user.username)
userprofile_instance = get_object_or_404(UserProfile,user = user_instance)
new_readlater        = Bookmarks.objects.get_or_create(user = userprofile_instance, article_slug = slug)
```

Where,

- `User` is the inbuilt Django user.
- `UserProfile` is extended `User` model.
- `Bookmarks`is a OneToMany relation to `UserProfile`.

  ```
  class Bookmarks(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, default = 1)
      read_later = models.CharField(default = "", max_length = 120)
  ```

I know, that bookmark function can be invoked by redirecting to the bookmark page url and hence bookmarks can be saved. But I don't want to redirect to the bookmark page, instead want to add it in the article page itself. How can I invoke the same bookmark saving function that handles the bookmark information on button click?

Comment: As you appear to know from the tags you've used, you would use Javascript for this. What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : I have edited the question, elaborating the needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question, what you need to do is make an ajax POST call when you submit the button in the webpage:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "url_to_call",
        type: "POST",
        data: {  csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}", //django needs this
                 data_item: mydata},
        timeout:0,
        success: function(data){//do something when done
                          //data will be the string returned by HTTPResponse
        }
}
```

And in your views.py return a `HTTPResponse`

```
response = HttpResponse("Here is some data to send back to the webpage")
```

This will keep you on the same page, without redirecting

Comment: Thanks..I am really new to ajax but this worked. Under `data`, `csrfmiddlewaretoken : $('input[name = csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()` is need for it to work , else it throws `403` invalid `csrf token` error.

Comment: @build_code sorry, I forgot to add that. I've edited the answer to include it. If you use Django templates, you can just put in {{ csrf_token }}

Comment: I have `{% csrf_token %}` mentioned under every form in templates but still threw 403 error. I realised that `csrfmiddlewaretoken : $('input[name = csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()` need to be present for it to work. Any idea why?